# Как сделать border для маркера?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В списке под каждым `li` стоит `border-bottom`, но он не распространяется на маркер. Можно ли как то подчеркнуть `li` вместе с маркером?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант через псевдоэлемент:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.85rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor</li>
    <li>Amet</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Генерировать вручную?

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
li:before {
  content: attr(data-number);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li data-number="1"></li>
  <li data-number="2"></li>
  <li data-number="3"></li>
  <li data-number="4"></li>
</ol>
```